# pythonでforループで自動でDataFrameの名前を変えたい

Tags: python, pandas

for i in range(10):
　dfi=pd.DataFrame({ 'A','B'})

みたいにしたとき、dfiのiの部分が1,2,3,...と変わって結果的に
df1
df2
df3
.
.
df10
という名前のDataFrameが作成されるようなプログラムを組みたいのです。
超初心者で恐縮ですが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

本題ではないと思いますが、`pd.DataFrame({'A','B'})`はエラーになるので、`pd.DataFrame(['A','B'])`に変更して回答しておきます。

質問のとおりに回答すると、次のように書くことでできます。

```
for i in range(10):
    exec("df"+ str(i) + " = pd.DataFrame(['A','B'])")
```

また、python3.6以降であれば`f文字列`を使って次のように書くこともできます。

```
for i in range(10):
    exec(f"df{i} = pd.DataFrame(['A','B'])")
```

しかしながら、一般的にはリストを使うのが普通だし、その方が便利です。

```
for i in range(10):
    df[i] = pd.DataFrame(['A','B'])")
```

また、Pythonの繰り返しは遅いので、Pandasではできるだけ配列を使うのも避けて１つのdfにまとめて処理をするほうがベターです。